# Como puedo eliminar una cadena de un array string(c++)

Tags: c++, dev-c++

Tengo una duda de como eliminar una posición y cadena de una string que utilizo para validar con regex
Lo que tengo que hacer es crear dos archivos uno donde mande los datos de las validaciones correctas  y otro archivo donde mande las incorrectas
Lo que trato de hacer es que en los if valide e imprima las correctas y en else tomo la incorrecta y la copio a otro array de string para luego imprimir en el archivo de error de validación solo que no puedo eliminar la posición ni la cadena que almacena por que en el archivo de validaciones correctas me imprime las incorrectas
Me podrían ayudar .

````
   string cadena[60];
   string cadenaError[60];
  cout<<"Ingrese cadena valida : "<<endl;
do{

      fflush(stdin);
      //cin>>cadena[x];
      //gets(cadena[x]);
      getline(cin,cadena[x]);
      fflush(stdin);

      if(std::regex_match(cadena[x],salida))
          {
              ban=true;
          }

      x++;
      
  
      
  
}while(ban!=true);
  
      Valcorrectas = fopen("resultado_analisis.txt","w");
      Valerroneas = fopen("resultado_analisis.txt","w");
while(i<x)
  {
     cout<<"\n"<<cadena[i];

     if(std::regex_match(cadena[i],letra))//Valido con regex las cadenas ingresadas
     {
         cout<<"\t Letra";
         strcpy(palabra,"letra");
     }
          else if(std::regex_match(cadena[i],digito))
          {
              cout<<"\t Digito ";
              strcpy(palabra,"digito");
          }
else{//Aqui trato de copiar la validacion que no es correcta y copiarla a otra para eliminar y asi no lo imprima en el archivo de validaciones correctas
       cout<<"\t No es correcta ";
       strcpy(palabra,"Incorrecta");
      cadenaError[ii]=cadena[i];
      cadena[i]=0;
    
     for(int o = 0; o < cadena1[ii].size(); o++){
          fputc(cadena1[ii][o],Valerroneas );
     }
    
      ii++;
     }//Fin del else 
     
     for(int o = 0; o < cadena[i].size(); o++){
          fputc(cadena[i][o],Valcorrectas );
     }
     fputc(' ',d);
     for(int o = 0; o < strlen(palabra); o++){
          fputc(palabra[o],Valcorrectas );
     }
     
     
     fputc('\n',Valcorrectas );
      i++;
      
      
  }
  cout<<"\n";
  fclose(d);
   fclose(e);//Cierro flujo de los archivos ```
````

Answer (score 0):

**Tabula correctamente el código**

Primera recomendación, mucho más útil de lo que crees. Un código bien tabulado es más facil de seguir y muchos errores se encuentran con más facilidad.

Aprende a tabular el código, es una inversión de futuro.

**No mezcles stdin con cin**

`stdin` es la entrada estándar de C, mientras que `cin` lo es de C++.

No mezcles ambos mecanismos porque el resultado puede ser desastroso. Ahora mismo te funciona porque ambas entradas están sincronizadas, pero eso puede cambiar en cualquier momento. Basta con hacer una llamada tal que `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` para que cada mecanismo vaya por su lado.

Para limpiar `cin` basta con hacer uso del método `ignore`:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<int>::max(), '\n');
```

Por otro lado, error por desgracia demasiado típico: No se debe usar `fflush` con `stdin`. `fflush` está pensado para ser utilizado únicamente con dispositivos de salida. En el caso de los dispositivos de entrada su comportamiento es indefinido.

**Eliminar un string**

En un array no es posible eliminar un elemento cualquiera. Los arrays tienen un tamaño fijo y los diferentes elementos ocupan posiciones consecutivas en memoria.

Lo más parecido a *eliminar* sería vaciar ese string, que es lo que tu estás intentando pero de forma incorrecta:

```
cadena[i] = 0;
```

Un `string` no se puede igualar a un `int` y, de poder hacerse, no te iba a gustar el resultado, ya que la conversión natural sería guardar en `cadena` un dígito: `"0"`, y tu lo que quieres es vaciar ese `string`.

Para hacer esto puedes probar a guardar una cadena vacía:

```
cadena[i] = "";
```

O puedes llamar al método `clear`:

```
cadena[i].clear();
```

Y ahora, para guardar la cadena, basta con comprobar antes si la cadena está vacía o no:

```
if (!cadena[i].empty())
{
    // Guardar en Valcorrectas
}
```

Llegados a este punto, nota que C++ tiene sus propios objetos para escribir en archivos. Una ventaja que te proporcionan estos objetos es que puedes guardar los strings de forma mucho más natural:

```
std::ofstream Valcorrectas("resultado_analisis.txt");
Valcorrectas.open();

std::string texto = "abcdef";
Valcorrectas << texto;
```